# Is there any built-in in method in spring to write an empty/null check method?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wrote this code, and I was wondering if there was a built-in method from spring that does the same thing as this method.

```java
public static String map(String value) {
    return value != null && value.isEmpty() ? null : value;
}
```

I found `ObjectUtil`, but it didn't have any method that has the same functionality.

I would appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: There's nothing wrong in creating your own util methods (if you do so in a reusable way). After all, you might have to rework that logic sooner or later, and then it would not be the same as the logic by the built in method anymore. I would, however, recommend a better name for the method

Comment: As @Stultuske said there is nothing wrong by writing your own utils. 
You could also do `Optional.ofNullable(value).filter(String::isEmpty).orElse(null)` to achieve the same result. Or you can directly use the Optional result to handle the upcoming `if (result != null)` block by using it's is/ifPresent() method.

Comment: It will be difficult to find this functionality off-the-shelf as mostly the requirement is the other way around (return "" for empty String or null). But as Stultuske said, it is perfectly ok to write a small utility by oneself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code seems you just map the empty string to `null` instead of avoiding it at all.

```java
public static String map(String value) {
    return value != null && value.isEmpty() ? null : value;
}
```

If `value` is null it return value so null, if it's empty it returns null again.

If your intent  is to avoid null values, you should introduce the [NullObject pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern).

On java 8+ use the Optional as it is the same, but natively supported by the language.

As already shown in comments by Jan Schumacher, it helps you to easely filter the value further.

With your function you still need a null check, but using Optional you don't need it anymore and the code is much clearer.

You can even use the `@NotNull` annotation in the method signature, to help enforce null values to be propagated when not expected.